# How to conduct permutation using an arraylist

Tags: java

I am trying to compare the first element in an arraylist to the rest of the elements.

Then comparing the second element of the arraylist to the rest of the elements and so on until
the end of the arraylist.

The code is as below:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

    a.add("G1");
    a.add("G2");
    a.add("G3");
    a.add("G1");

    System.out.println(a.size());

    for(int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++){

        for(int j = 0; j<a.size(); j++){

        if(a.get(i) == a.get(j))
            System.out.println("Element: " + a.get(i)+ " at " + i + " and " + "Element: "+ a.get(j)+ " at " + j);

        }





    }
```

Comment: Use `String.equals()` method to compare string

Comment: Where is the problem you are getting?

Comment: The problem is that it would check element 0 against 1 then 2 so on but after this it would check element 1 against 0 then 1 and so on it should not compare the same elements twice.

Comment: I already figured that out. Take a look at my answer and let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
 if((a.get(i)).equals(a.get(j)))
```

instead of

```
 if(a.get(i) == a.get(j))
```

Morover start your initialization of `j = i+1` You have already checked these previous string so no need to start it again.

**EDIT**

You have to limit your outer loop to `i<a.size()-1` so that it wont check very last element with itself.

I hope this helps. if you need anymore help just ask.

Comment: Thanks, another issue is that every element must only be checked once any idea on how I could achieve this ? for example if the contents of the array were 

a.add("G1");//0
  a.add("G2");//1
  a.add("G3");//2
  a.add("G1");//3 
  a.add("G2");//4 
  a.add("G2");//5
  a.add("G3");//6
  

  
 }

Comment: @SandeepJohal I updated the answer. The issue you are referring to already stated in answer by others.

Comment: @SandeepJohal I think I misunderstood your question. I didnt get it. Can you make that edit in your question and let me know when you do it.

Answer (score 1):

`==` is reference equality (e.g do these two objects point to the same location in memory).  For object equality, use `.equals()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, instead of yours.

```
for(int i = 0; i<a.size()-1; i++){

    for(int j = i+1; j<a.size(); j++){

    if(a.get(i).equals(a.get(j)))
        System.out.println("Element: " + a.get(i)+ " at " + i + " and " + "Element: "+ a.get(j)+ " at " + j);

    }
```

Hope that helps.. :)

Comment: Additionally each loop through will end 1 short with that a.size()-1 on the interior loop.  a.size()-1 is acceptable on the outer loop so then it doesn't jump through one extra time at the end when there's only one entry to compare with.

Comment: oh, my bad...
replace == with .equals and the i loop should end at a.size()-1 not the j loop.

Comment: @ArchitSaxena Better you edit this in your answer. Make it complete.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, since you're using Strings, instead of using ==, which is referential equality, as in are the memory addresses the same, you want to use `.equals()` which will compare the two strings by their actual values.

As for your for-loop, you can make it slightly more efficient by doing this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size()-1; i++)
{
    for (int j = i+1; j < a.size(); j++)
    {
        if(a.get(i).equals(a.get(j)))
        {
            System.out.println("Element: " + a.get(i)+ " at " + i + " and " + "Element: "+ a.get(j)+ " at " + j);
        }

    }
}
```

Since there are times when you already compare a[i] with a[j], the result will be the same if you do a[j] equals a[i], so you can just skip over them.  This also saves you from checking a[i] equals a[j] when j and i are the same.